# tvOS 10. PreferredFocusView is deprecated. How do I change to preferredFocusEnvironment?

Tags: objective-c, tvos, apple-tv

I have a subview for which I have overridden the preferredFocusedView. The subclass has a UIView called viewToFocus. I check if that view exists, if it does I focus that view, if not I return the preferredFocusedView of the parent.

Since I updated to tvOS 10 today I am getting the following error:

> 'preferredFocusedView' is deprecated: first deprecated in tvOS 10.0 -
>   Use -preferredFocusEnvironments instead.

I cant find anywhere in the documentation that explains how preferredFocusEnvironment is to be implemented. In the documentation found [Supporting Focus within Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH5-SW14), it says to

> Override the preferredFocusedView to specify where focus should start
>   by default.

I tried adding the UIFocusEnvironment Protocol but I am not sure how to replace the functionality of 'preferredFocusedView' with it.

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    if (self.viewToFocus) {
        UIView *newView = self.viewToFocus;
        self.viewToFocus = nil;

        return newView;
    } else {
        return [super preferredFocusedView];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass an array of views as a result of `preferredFocusEnvironments` call instead of just one view as it was before. This views must be ordered by the focus priority. So, if you have 3 `UIButton` items on your `UIViewController` the `preferredFocusEnvironments` property can be implemented the following:

```
- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments {

    return @[self.b3, self.b2, self.b1];
}
```

In your case you just need to return a `@[newView]` as a result.