# how to use preferredFocusEnvironments insted of preferredFocusedView for ios 10?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvos9.1, tvos10

I am working on apple tv os application. I want to move focus on particular UiButton but I don't know how to use preferredFocusEnvironments instead of preferredFocusedView ?

I am able to use preferredFocusedView but for this variable is deprecated.

so anyone can help me for this issue?

Comment: Check this answer please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479180/tvos-10-preferredfocusview-is-deprecated-how-do-i-change-to-preferredfocusenvi/39490125#39490125

Comment: thanks  Roman Podymov.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to solve this question by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39490125/3818903)

What i did is as below :

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewTemp: UIView!
override var preferredFocusEnvironments : [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    //Condition
    return [viewTemp]
}
```

insted of this.

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    //Condition
    return viewTemp
}
```

Comment: This is good way, whenever you find solution you suggest your aswer